# CheckBox background issue in Android + Xperia x10

Tags: android, checkbox, background

I am trying to set backgroundColor of CheckBox by code. 
Its not working on xperia series. same code has tested other deices which is working on samsung and motorola.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

that is showing black background in xperia only. 
If I am doing that by xml that is working.

Please let me know if there is any known issue for xperia series.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some issue with xperia to setBackgroundColor(). but it works with setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
checkBox.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
checkBox.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

If this doesn`t work then setBackgroundColor is broken for Xperia x10

Comment: What about other setBackground (setBackgroundDrawable) methods? Does setBackgroundColor works for other Views?

Comment: If I am trying to add image resource as a background by code that is also not working in xperia as working on other devices.

Comment: Then sorry I guess setBackgroundColor is broken for Xperia x10. Post ticket to official support or something like this, and close question..

Answer (score 0):

it has this issue on xperia series ,you can declare the defalut value in layout.xml file,i set the background image ok , android:background="@drawable/test" , then set "setBackgroundResource" int the code, first of  all set the default value in the layout.xml

why the last answer be deleted when  i answer by chinease ? :(