# Checkbox Background issue on Xperia

Tags: android, checkbox, background, sony-xperia

As the title says, I got a problem with `Checkbox` `Background` on Xperia phones. The code is working fine on every devices but Xperia ones. It simply shows no background.

```
myCheckbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customBackground);
```

Neither does `myCheckbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

As stated in [this other post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139747/checkbox-background-issue-in-android-xperia-x10), `Background` methods seem broken on Xperia. I tried the given fix, and it works well for colors.

```
myCheckbox.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myCheckbox.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Problem is there is no `setDrawingCacheBackgroundResource(int)` method for me.

Hence there are my two questions :

1- Does someone know how to fix it ?

2- If someone knows, how can I know if the phone actually is a Xperia ? Just to do something like

```
if( /*phone is Xperia*/ )
    /*Use fix*/
else
    /*Proceed normaly*/
```

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this but I find it not satisfying :

```
myCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean checked)
    {
        layout_checkboxsubstitute.setBackgroundResource(checked ? R.drawable.customBackgroundStateOn : R.drawable.customBackgroundStateOff);
    }
});
```

I created a `Layout` and show it instead of `Checkbox` itself. I have to change `Background` manually. I'd rather stay with `myCheckbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customBackground);` which is way simplier.

Does someone have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with xperia for setBackgroundColor(). but it works with setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
checkBox.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
checkBox.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

In case if you want to get phone manufacturer and model you can get it using,

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;
```

Comment: I already did this, but as stated I don't want to change BackgroundColor but I would have needed a `setDrawingCacheBackgroundResource(int)` method.

Comment: That is an issue in xperia, so instead you can replace checkbox as a button or something with different backgrounds to indicated whether it is checked/pressed or not.